# How to display Raspberry´s local IP Adress on a HTML site?

Tags: networking, lighttpd, php

I run raspberry with a strating webbrowser in kiosk mode and want to display the local ip-adress of my raspberry.

How can I do this? I Use PHP (httpd)
I tried with

```
<?php print_r($SERVER); ?>
```

but this will give me only 127.0.0.1

I want the same output like

```
sudo ip addr show
```

output:

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:7c:ce:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.28/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this and it works!
`<?php
$host = gethostname();
$ip = gethostbyname($host);
echo $ip; 
?>`

Comment: feel free to answer your own question!

Comment: i cant answer my own question during the first hours....

Comment: by the way, my problem isn´t solved. I get the IP 127.0.0.1  - too bad!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
<?php system("hostname -I"); ?>
```