# Write current IP adress eth0 to a file

Tags: iptables, file

I need to store the current IP adress of my Raspberry Pi into a file. Can someone tell me how to do this?

The goal is to create a file in `/var/www/ipadress.txt` with this content:

> 192.168.0.28

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:7c:ce:18
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.28  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:1762 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1044 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX bytes:267534 (261.2 KiB)  TX bytes:233261 (227.7 KiB)
```

I need the part: **192.168.0.28**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that this command will give you the IP address only:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'
```

To output it to a file:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' > "/var/www/ipadress.txt"
```

Comment: i had to change it to: 
`$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet Adresse:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' > "/var/www/ipadress.txt"` because im using the raspberry in german language

Answer (score 0):

language independent version:

```
ifconfig | grep -o "\([0-9]\+\.\)\+[0-9]\+" | head -n 1
```

or, as it was noted in [another question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/10496/7274)

```
hostname -I
```

might do the trick as well.